# How would you test this API call in React?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-router, react-testing-library

I have been stuck on how to do this for days guys, please help I'm desperate. I understand with React testing we aren't testing the implementation but the result of the implementation i.e what the user sees.

The user enters a search term, submits, and the API call is made. Once successful, they are sent to a different route (using react router dom) where the retrieved array is mapped and displayed.

Thus, the API call is made in one component and retrieved in the next component using the Context API.

**The API call:**

```
export const spotifyTokenAndSearch = (query, state) => {

  spotifyToken
    .post("", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: clientMix,
      },
    })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      const accessToken = data;

      spotifyQuery
        .get("/search", {
          headers: {
            Authorization: accessToken,
          },
          params: { query },
        })
        .then(({ data }) => {
          state(data);
        });
    });
```

**Where the API call is made:**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";

 const Search = () => {
  const {
    spotifyTokenAndSearch,
    term,
    setTerm,
    setSubmittedTerm,
    submittedTerm,
    setItems,
    navigate,
  } = useContext(SearchContext);

    const handleButtonClick = (term) => {
    setSubmittedTerm(term);
    spotifyTokenAndSearch(submittedTerm, setItems);
    navigate("/artists");
  };

  return (
    <main className="searchContainer container-fluid d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <form
        onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
          <div
            <input
              role="search-all-input"
              value={term}
              onChange={({ target }) => setTerm(target.value)}
              type="text"
            />
          </div>
        <div>
          <button
            onClick(() => handleButtonClick(term)) 
            disabled={!term}
            type="button"
          >
            Artists
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </main>
)}
```

**Where the resulting response from the API is mapped:**

```
import React, {useContext} from "react";
import ArtistList from "./ArtistList";


const SearchList = () => {
  const {
    items
  } = useContext(SearchContext);

 const renderArtists = () => {
    if (items.length === 0) {
      return (
        <section>
          <div>
            <h2>Artists</h2>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div className="ui active centered inline loader"></div>
          </div>
        <section>
      );
    } else if (items.length > 0) {
      return (
        <section>
          <div>
            <h2>Artists</h2>
          </div>
          <ArtistList
            items={items}
          />
        </section>
      );
    }
  };

    return (
    <main>
      {renderArtists()}
    </main>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I seemed to have figured it out. I installed MSW (Mock Service Worker) which intercepted the API calls as they happened in the test and returned a response that I could use to map over for my tests.

I created the server and the handlers (which return the mocked response). Because I wanted to test when the API call was successful (results from the search) and unsuccessful (no results from the search), my handler is a function that takes an argument that modifies the returned mocked response.

**Handler** which deals with mocking the responses from the two API calls:

```
import { rest } from "msw";

export const artistHandlers = (mock) => {
  let data = mock;

  return [
    rest.post("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", (req, res, ctx) => {
      return res(ctx.status(200, "success"));
    }),

    rest.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search", (req, res, ctx) => {
      return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.body(data));
    }),
  ];
};
```

**Server** which intercepts the API call in the tests

```
import { setupServer } from "msw/node";
import { artistHandlers } from "./handlers";
import { artistResultsSuccess } from "../api/mock";

export const artistServer = setupServer(
  ...artistHandlers(artistResultsSuccess)
);
```

**Tests** which use an instance of the server for the last test (for the no results response)

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { NavigationAndStore } from "../../../test-utils/test-utils";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import SearchContext, { SearchStore } from "../../contexts/SearchStore";
import Search from "../Search";
import SearchList from "../SearchList";
import { artistServer } from "../../mocks/servers";
import { artistHandlers } from "../../mocks/handlers";
import { history } from "../../../test-utils";
import { artistResultsNone } from "../../api/mock";

beforeAll(() => artistServer.listen());

afterEach(() => artistServer.resetHandlers());

afterAll(() => artistServer.close());

const WrapperComponent = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <NavigationAndStore context={SearchContext} store={SearchStore}>
      {children}
    </NavigationAndStore>
  );
};

const customRender = (wrapper, components) => {
  return render(components, { wrapper: wrapper });
};

test("When a search term is entered, submitted and the API call is successful (array of artists)", async () => {
  const user = userEvent.setup();

  const { getByRole, findAllByRole } = customRender(
    WrapperComponent,
    <>
      <Search />
      <SearchList />
    </>
  );

  const input = getByRole("search-all-input");
  const submitButton = getByRole("button", { name: "Artists" });

  await user.type(input, "hi");

  user.click(submitButton);

  expect(await findAllByRole("artist-card")).toHaveLength(10);
});

test("When the API call is successful but no results are returned", async () => {
  artistServer.use(...artistHandlers(artistResultsNone));

  const user = userEvent.setup();

  const { getByRole, findByRole } = customRender(
    WrapperComponent,
    <>
      <Search />
      <SearchList />
    </>
  );

  const input = getByRole("search-all-input");
  const submitButton = getByRole("button", { name: "Artists" });

  await user.type(input, "hi");

  user.click(submitButton);

  expect(
    await findByRole("heading", { name: "No results found" })
  ).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```